# How to connect existing MEW to Trezor?

Tags: bitcoin-core, ethereum, trezor

I have got my new Trezor but I don't know how to connect my existing myetherwallet to trezor ether address ?

Is there any way I can directly import and connect to trezor ?
Or I have to create a new myetherwallet with trezor and transfer ethereum and other erc20 coins from old myetherwallet to new ether trezor address ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import your existing MEW to Trezor wallet.

It is the security of a hardware wallet which makes it worth the price, and that is why the wallet is generated in Trezor offline.

Thus, the only way is to create a new wallet in Trezor. Transfer all your coins from existing MEW to Trezor. And after that, you can use Trezor with MEW to send or receive other alt coins which Trezor don't have support directly.

Hope this answers your query.